# Its showing me a module not found error but the module is installed on my computer

Tags: python, error-handling

Whenever I run my code code I am getting an Module Not Found Error for the tkvideoplayer module

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Code\Proj1\Video_Player.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkvideoplayer import TkinterVideo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkvideoplayer'"
```

```
from tkinter import *
from tkvideoplayer import TkinterVideo
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
window = Tk()
window.title("My Video Player")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.config(bg="Turquoise")
heading = Label(window, text="My Video Player", bg="Orange Red", fg="white", font="4 none bold")
heading.config(anchor=CENTER)


def openFile():
    file = askopenfile(mode="r", filetypes=[('Video Files', '*.mp4', '*.mov')])
    if file is not None:
        global filename
        filename = file.name
        global videoPlayer
        videoPlayer = TkinterVideo(master=window, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
        videoPlayer.load(r"{}".format(filename))
        videoPlayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        videoPlayer.play()


def playFile():
    videoPlayer.play()


def stopFile():
    videoPlayer.stop()


def pauseFile():
    videoPlayer.pause()


openbtn = Button(window, text="Open", command=lambda: openFile())
stopbtn = Button(window, text="Stop", command=lambda: stopFile())
playbtn = Button(window, text="Play", command=lambda: playFile())
pausebtn = Button(window, text="Pause", command=lambda: pauseFile())

openbtn.pack(side=TOP, pady=2)
stopbtn.pack(side=TOP, pady=4)
playbtn.pack(side=TOP, pady=3)
pausebtn.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)
heading.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do you know it is installed? If you used "pip", ensure that it uses the same Python "--version" as the Python with which you run the code.

Comment: Are you using pycharm? if so you need to install it through the pycharm terminal.

Comment: The module should be installed in the enviroment you run your code in.

Comment: I am using PyCharm

Comment: And I did install it through the PyCharm terminal

Comment: it's showing that it is already installed but my program is not detecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my code then made a different video player and this one doesn't give an error

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo


def update_duration(event):
    """ updates the duration after finding the duration """
    end_time["text"] = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=vid_player.duration()))
    progress_slider["to"] = vid_player.duration()


def update_scale(event):
    """ updates the scale value """
    progress_slider.set(vid_player.current_duration())


def load_video():
    """ loads the video """
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    if file_path:
        vid_player.load(file_path)

        progress_slider.config(to=0, from_=0)
        progress_slider.set(0)
        play_pause_btn["text"] = "Play"


def seek(value):
    """ used to seek a specific timeframe """
    vid_player.seek(int(value))


def skip(value: int):
    """ skip seconds """
    vid_player.skip_sec(value)
    progress_slider.set(progress_slider.get() + value)


def play_pause():
    """ pauses and plays """
    if vid_player.is_paused():
        vid_player.play()
        play_pause_btn["text"] = "Pause"

    else:
        vid_player.pause()
        play_pause_btn["text"] = "Play"


def video_ended(event):
    """ handle video ended """
    progress_slider.set(progress_slider["to"])
    play_pause_btn["text"] = "Play"


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Video Player")

load_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Load", command=load_video)
load_btn.pack()

vid_player = TkinterVideo(scaled=True, pre_load=False, master=root)
vid_player.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

play_pause_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Play", command=play_pause)
play_pause_btn.pack()

skip_plus_5sec = tk.Button(root, text="Skip -5 sec", command=lambda: skip(-5))
skip_plus_5sec.pack(side="left")

start_time = tk.Label(root, text=str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)))
start_time.pack(side="left")

progress_slider = tk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=0, orient="horizontal", command=seek)
progress_slider.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)

end_time = tk.Label(root, text=str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)))
end_time.pack(side="left")

vid_player.bind("<<Duration>>", update_duration)
vid_player.bind("<<SecondChanged>>", update_scale)
vid_player.bind("<<Ended>>", video_ended )

skip_plus_5sec = tk.Button(root, text="Skip +5 sec", command=lambda: skip(5))
skip_plus_5sec.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You already had the answer in your first edit. Why did you remove that? Now this answer looks more like a question than an answer.

Comment: it's a answer to my previous question and it's a new question

Comment: if you have a new question you should ask another one, not edit the existing answer to include a new question.

Comment: I have already asked a new question. I also added the new question here because if people don't find the new question that has been asked they can find it here

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Library/ Module first.
Use this link.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-tkinter-in-windows/

then you need to install the module for tkvideoplayer blow link will help.

https://github.com/huskeee/tkvideo/blob/master/README.md

Finally you can run your code.

Comment: tkvideo and tkvideoplayer are different libraries

Comment: yes they are 2 different libraries

Comment: And I have tkinter installed it is not detecting the tkvideoplayer module but its installed

Comment: whenever i try to install it shows me that its already been installed but when i run my code it gives the module not found error

Comment: also uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't work I already tried that

Comment: And I do have the latest version

Comment: @devesh thakur The first link in your answer are the instructions to download the tkinter module and I already have it installed and the second link are the instructions to download the tkvideo module not tkvideoplayer

Comment: and my problem is that my program is not detecting the tkvideoplayer module

Comment: @Michael Butscher I know that it is already installed because whenever i type pip list in the command prompt tkvideoplayer is in the list.